# seems vs. seems to be vs. seems like

Tags: word-choice, phrases

I've noticed that “seems like” is the most commonly used phrase out of the three.

If I were to say that Los Angeles appears to be a nice city, would using any of these three phrases work because “to seem” means to “appear to be”?

1. Los Angeles seems a nice city.
2. Los Angeles seems to be a nice city.
3. Los Angeles seems like a nice city.

Comment: All are correct in a certain sense. Please check the meaning and usage of *seem* with the different phrases following it. They **do not** necessarily mean the same and **are not** necessarily used interchangeably in any context.

Answer (score 2):

1.*Los Angeles seems a nice city.* (This is incorrect. You can't use a noun if you don't use 'to be' in this structure)

2.Los Angeles seems/appears to be a nice city. (Both 'seems' and 'appears' can be used here.)

3.Los Angeles seems like a nice city.(Only 'seems' works here)

'seems'/'appears' + adj. = It seems/appears nice.

'seems'/'appears' + to be + Noun phrase = It seems/appears to be a nice city.

'seems' + like + noun phrase - It seems like a nice city.

Comment: *Los Angeles seems a nice city* is fine. It's just ordinary ellipsis, like *The book seems a bit long for my taste*: "to be" is not at all required to make those constructions work. Your whole set of "correct" examples seems more than a little prescriptive.

Comment: 'seems a nice city' - 'a nice city' is a noun phrase. As stated above 'seems' cannot be directly followed by a noun phrase. 'seems a bit long'- 'a bit long' is an adjective phrase. Noun phrases and adjective phrases are not the same. 'Seems' can be directly followed by an adjective phrase.When non-native speakers omit words, I do not consider it 'ellipsis'; it's an error.  Is correct English considered 'prescriptive'?

Comment: It works. Grammar has no problem with "seems a nice city".

Comment: Please cite your sources, or use "comments".

Comment: The Oxford dictionary does not give an example sentence for seem + noun. It does give examples for all the other patterns I have listed.

Comment: In speech, it is an acceptable ellipsis, I think.  The Brits use it a lot.

Comment: Consider" (*) *seems a city* vs *seems a nice city*. The first is problematic (and can be fixed by inserting "to be") but the second works. The words are spread out, but I think the operational phrase is "seems nice" - that's why "to be" isn't needed in the second case.

Comment: If one wants to be really pedantic, one can argue that *like* in *seems like* is redundant, because the meaning of *seems* already incorporates the idea expressed by *like*. The phrase is, however, too widely entrenched for such an argument to have much force.

Comment: [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/seem) is happy with an example showing to-be-deletion before a noun phrase: 'To everyone who knew them, they seemed an ideal couple.'  // You fail to mention _which_ 'Oxford Dictionary' you are referring to. Many people assume that the one they're citing has to be OED; it's usually Lexico.

Comment: This answer seems wrong in respect of (1), which is a common, unambiguous and clear construction. If this seems a problem to you, consult  ngram for "seems to be a problem"/"seems a problem". Both were  used equally until about 1940, after which "seems to be a problem" became more popular.

Comment: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/seem) however **does** give an example sentence for [seem] + [NP]: << **Seem** as a linking verb: Seem as a linking verb is followed by an adjective or, less commonly, a noun:

• It seems strange that no one noticed that the window was broken. (+ adjective)

• Glenda seems happier these days.

• Buying a new car seems a complete waste of money to me. >> I suspect there's at least one in OED, too. // The use of the descriptor 'correct English' to equate to 'my preferred style' is considered prescriptive.